# Subtraction scheme in Renormalization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

What is the difference between subtraction scheme used in DREG and counter terms added to the Lagrangian?

Answer (score 2):

The idea of re-normalization is to treat the parameters in the theory as "bare" and to accept that, in perturbation theory at least, they may be infinite. The observed parameters are then going to be the difference of two values that, when you do the momentum integrals, for example, will diverge.

The goal of a regularization scheme is to make sense of subtracting infinity from infinity. The usual way is to arrange that the values you want to subtract are finite until you take some limit. Then you want to take the limit of the difference only, and see that it produces a well defined limiting value.

DREG does it by changing the dimension of space time in the problem. Then it calculates the values to be calculated. Then it demonstrates that, order by order, both the infinities and dependence on the dimension can always be pushed to a higher order of perturbation. In re-normalizable theories this can be done with a finite number of parameters to set the values in the theory. This means you can compare to experiment by calculating things like reaction rates or magnetic moments and so on.

Counter terms achieve it by adding things to the Lagrangian, with a parameter that allows setting them back to zero at the end. These values then allow calculating the desired parameters. Again, at each order of perturbation in a renormalizable theory, dependence on the added parameter can be pushed to higher orders of perturbation.

Effectively, what the counter term does, is add new physics that just nicely kills off the infinities. But only just enough to make the integrals finite. And in such a way you can turn them off at the end.

There are several other regularization schemes. Each has advantages and disadvantages. Some of them are what people sometimes dismissively refer to as "formalism." DREG for example, seems to be something of a mathematical cheat. What does it mean for the dimension to be a non-integer real number? Or a non-integer complex number?  Are integrals really defined when the dimension is $(0.2+0.8i)$?

Basically, you choose your regulation scheme on the basis of what you are trying to do and what you are comfortable with. Some schemes, for example, mess with gauge invariance. If your counter term is not gauge invariant, for example, you have got some significant reason to think carefully about it. Some mess with relativistic invariance, such as a momentum cut off. Others are very troublesome for other reasons. For example, non-local regulation introduces a non-locality to the interaction, which renders the integrals finite. But non-locality comes with its own large collection of intellectual challenges that are at least as old as Newton.